# When in editing session and merging polygons, feature labels for each are not from desired field in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, default

In my mxd, the polygons in the layer that I'm editing display a label from a certain chosen field. But when I am editing and merging these polygons, the label displayed in the 'Merge' dialogue box is from a different, less relevant field.

How do I make the 'Merge' dialogue box display the labels as shown in that polygon layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Merge window (along with the Identify tool and other toolbar windows) use the Display property set on the Layer, not the labels.

In your Table of Content right click your layer > Properties > Display Tab > Change the Display Expression Field to the field you want shown when editing/identifying.
[image]